# 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Tags: c#, .net, ssas, .net-5, tabular

I want to connect to my local tabular server from my asp.netcore project (.net 5) according to the link below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tom/connect-to-existing-analysis-services-tabular-server-and-database?view=asallproducts-allversions

```
string ConnectionString = "DataSource=localhost";

using var server = new Server();

server.Connect(ConnectionString);

Console.WriteLine("Connection established successfully.");
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
Console.WriteLine("Server name:\t\t{0}", server.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Server product name:\t{0}", server.ProductName);
Console.WriteLine("Server product level:\t{0}", server.ProductLevel);
Console.WriteLine("Server version:\t\t{0}", server.Version);
Console.ResetColor();
Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to close this console window.");

return Ok();
```

I get this error when I call the action :

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext from assembly mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.IdentityResolver.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.XmlaClient.Connect(String connectionString, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Connect(String connectionString, String sessionId, ObjectExpansion expansionType)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Connect(String connectionString, String sessionId)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Core.Server.Connect(String connectionString)
```

Answer (score 2):

It was because I was using this package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular/
that for .NET and for .NET Core this package must be used :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.NetCore.retail.amd64